# how to build html body using list elements

Tags: python, html

```
html_body = """\
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<table border="1">
%s
</table>
</body>
</html>
""" % (html_content)

html_contents = [<tr><td>Name</td><td>id</td></tr> , <tr><td>Smith</td><td>1001</td></tr>]
```

I am trying to for html body from a list so that it can be sent in an email. How can i put all the elements of html_content list in the html_body above ? Better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join()` to join strings from the list:

```
>>> html_contents = ['<tr><td>Name</td><td>id</td></tr>' , '<tr><td>Smith</td><td>1001</td></tr>']
>>> html_body = """\
... <html>
... <head>
... </head>
... <body>
... <br>
... <table border="1">
... %s
... </table>
... </body>
... </html>
... """ % ("".join(html_contents))
>>> print html_body
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>id</td></tr><tr><td>Smith</td><td>1001</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), you could build the HTML like this:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.builder as builder
E = builder.E

page = (
    E.html(       # create an Element called "html"
        E.head(),
        E.body(
            E.br(),
            E.table(
                E.tr(
                    E.td("Name"),
                    E.td("id")
                ),
                E.tr(
                    E.td("Smith"),
                    E.td("1001")
                ),
                border="1")
        )
    )
)

print(LH.tostring(page, pretty_print=True))
```

yields

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<br><table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>1001</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This makes the structure of the HTML apparent, and you're more likely to end up with valid HTML.